# Finding the boundary of a right angled triangle given the area

Tags: c#, geometry, binary-search

I am trying to find the points `p1, p2` as an imaginary line (yellow) moves in the direction of the red arrow. The points `p1, p2, p3, p4` will bound a user-input area `A`. What I want is the "first" occurrence of the given area as the yellow line sweeps from right to left.

The points `p3, p4`, `A` and `angle` are known.

I have initially tried something like (psudeocode):

```
from right to left of the triangle:
    Move p1 to the left on the x-axis by epsilon
    Calculate p2 and the area bounded by (p1,p2,p3,p4)
    if(area < error): return the result
    else: continue
```

However, this solution may not converge as the epsilon value may be "jumped" over. (for example, if i am trying to find the number 4 by incrementing the number 0 by 0.3 each time, it will never hit 4).

As such, I have tried a binary search method, but failed as I realised that the area bounded is not monotonically increasing (for example, the area bounded by the green line and the left most end of the triangle is also possible solution returned by binary searchig).

My question is is there an algorithm to solve this type of problem? And that it is guaranteed to converge?

[image]

Comment: The problem seems to be under-specified; what is the slope from `p4` to the top left corner? I think there is nothing algorithmic about it; I believe this can be expressed with a 'closed formula'.

Comment: I think this is not the best place to ask that, you want a mathematical algorithm, try at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Codor I have updated the diagram. Basically there is a user-specified angle to produce the slope (which will intersect the line produced at p3).

Comment: Is this triangle right-angled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's right edge of triangle `(p3-p4)` has length `R`.

Let's `p1-p3` distance is `x`. Then trapezoid area is

```
A = 1/2 * x * (R + R - x * ctg(angle))
2*A = 2*x*R - x^2*ctg(angle)
x^2 * ctg(angle) - 2 * x * R + 2 * A = 0
```

solve this quadratic equation for unknown x, find whether proper root exists (in range `0..R*tg(angle)`)